# What does 18V signify here?

Tags: electric-circuits

So in this question in my textbook[image]

I am asked to find the current *i*. In the solution the relation $i=\frac{EMF_{net}}{R_{net}}$ is used to calculate the current. So here does the 18V signify the EMF of the cell? So then what is potential difference? Shouldn't the potential difference be 18V?
(Note: I have just started reading this chapter on electric current and I have never read about electricity before so I am sorry if it's a bad question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electromotive force (EMF) is the work done per unit charge on the charge carriers; while, potential difference is the work done per unit charge by the charge carriers. Thus, by conservation of energy ([Kirchhoff's voltage law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws)) the total EMF in a loop of a curcuit is equal to the total potential difference is a loop of the circuit. Therefore in this example the total potential difference is 18V.

Note that in a non-ideal cell thre is internal resistance and so there is a potential difference across this internal resistance. This means it appears that the potential difference across the rest of the loop is less than the EMF of the cell.

Comment: Just editted this in.

Comment: Yep understood now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

18 V is the net EMF of the circuit, which is provided by the battery. The total potential difference across the circuit is also 18 V.

EMF and potential difference are usually interchangeable, but sometimes you may deal with the potential difference across a component of your circuit (like a single resister) as opposed to the total or net potential difference.

Comment: When I was trying to understand this I came across a web page that said that EMF is always greater than potential difference. So in these types of questions do we just assume them to be the same unless otherwise stated?

Comment: Yes, although the EMF is slightly greater than potential difference, you can assume it's the same.

Comment: Alright thanks!